# Table Valued Function in EF 5?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Apologies if this isnt phrased very well, but after upgrading to `VS2012/.NET 4.5`, I know Table Valued Functions are possible in Entity Framework 5.

We use a custom datalayer / orm, and I cant find any code examples that dont use the EDMX model generator as this is of no use.

As a very wild guess I would say some code that defines the table value function will need adding in `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` .

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table valued function are not supported for Code-First strategy, only for Database-First with EDMX: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859577. Quote:

> TVFs are currently only supported in the Database First workflow.

Comment: It appears they are still not supported even with EF 6. Please vote for issue 818 on CodePlex. https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/818

Comment: I found the feature. It got postponed until after EF 6. Vote for it on their User Voice board here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2686351-code-first-support-for-table-valued-functions

Answer (score 2):

I was able to easily execute a Table Valued Function using EF 5 as follows:

```
int orderID = 100;
var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<Product>("Select * from [dbo].[tfn_GetOrderProducts](@p0)", orderID);
var results = query.ToList();
```

where Product can be any POCO class whose member names match up with the results of the table valued function.

This isn't a perfect solution -- it's not returning an IQueryable, so you can't use this as part of a larger LINQ query; however, in this case, it was all I needed.

Answer (score -1):

the following suggestion was removed from this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx. I've found this information that may be usefull to you.

> **Code First Approach**
>
> Entity Framework June 2011 CTP does not include Code First support for
>   TVFs. However, you can use DbContext against your TVFs. You can do
>   this by adding the DbContext template to your model. The steps to add
>   the template are the following:
>
> - Open NorthwindModel.edmx and right click on the canvas
> - Click on Add Code Generation Item…
> - Select ADO.NET DbContext Generator V4.2, enter a name for your template, and click Add